# With GItHub Actions is it possible to have an initial job with the output used in next multiple jobs?

Tags: github-actions

I wish to see if I can be smarter with my current GH Action and see if I can do a job .. with the output of that used in the subsequent jobs.

Here's my *current* pseudo-workflow:

```
Jobs:

  - build_test
   - step1: actions/checkout@v3
   - step2: build -configuration:debug

  - build_debug
   - step1: actions/checkout@v3
   - step2: build -configuration:release
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
Jobs:

   - prepare 
     - Step1: actions/checkout@v3

   - build-test (depends on 'prepare')
     - Step1: build --configuration:debug

   - build-deploy (depends on 'prepare'. uses checked out code from prepare)
     - Step1: build--configuration:release
```

```
                    /=> build-test
Jobs: => prepare => 
                   \=> build-deploy
```

Now before you suggest "use a matrix for debug/release" I've also given that a go . but then I ended up having two things:

1 - both runs *both* did `actions/checkout@v3`
2 - I had to have a lot of step-x: only do this if release. or only if debug.

which made the "step list" really long and .. crappy (in *my* opinion).

So is this possible?

Comment: I don't get what do you want, I think that you example doesn't show exactly what you want. How do you decide if you want to run `build-test` or `build-deploy`? Jobs are isolated from each other so you might need the checkout action everytime unless you want to upload/download artifacts from builds in previous jobs

Comment: `build-test` and `build-deploy` are jobs. so they run in parallel to each other. but they both need to depend on the first one, job `prepare`.

Comment: You can use outputs from jobs and use them in [`needs.JOB_ID.ouputs.OUTPUT`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs), and you can use [upload/download](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) actions to share artifacts

Comment: but the output from a job is a string? like ... what about the actual files which `actions/checkout@v3` does? or are each job "separate server instances" .. so it can't be done?  versus ... the same server but just with different jobs (aka processes) running parallel on the same server-instance with access to the exact same files?

Comment: _"or are each job "separate server instances""_ - yes.

Comment: Now, if you want to use the same server to perform those operations (each job), you can use a [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) instead.

Comment: awesome folks - thanks kindly for the help! i'll just stick with the same step in _both jobs_ to keep things simple.